# XSLT not working with display:none

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml is as below:

> ```
>      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>       <product>
>          <auto>
>             <admin>
>                 <date>01/01/2015</date>
>             </admin>
>             <report>
>                  <Fname>John</Fname>
>                  <Lname>ABC</Lname>
>             </report>
>         </auto>
>         <auto>
>              <admin>
>                  <date>02/02/2015</date>
>              </admin>
>              <report>
>                  <Fname>Tim</Fname>
>                  <Lname>DEF</Lname>
>              </report>
>         </auto>
>     </product>
> ```

my XSLT as below:

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>      <xsl:template match="/">
>       <html lang="en">
>       <head>
>            <title>Example</title>
>            <script type="text/javascript"> function toggleDisplay(element) { element.style.display = element.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; }       </script>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <h1>Example</h1>
>     <xsl:apply-templates/>
>   </body>
>   </html>
>  </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template match="product/auto">
> <ul>
>   <a onclick="toggleDisplay(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]); return false;" href="#">
>     <xsl:value-of select="report/Fname"/>
>   </a>
>   <xsl:apply-templates select="admin"/>
>   <xsl:apply-templates select="report"/>
> </ul>
>   </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template match="admin">
>    <ul style="display:none;">
>   <li>
>     Admin: <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
>     <br/>
>   </li>
> </ul>
>   </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template match="report">
>    <ul style="display:none;">
>   Report: <xsl:value-of select="Lname"/>
>   <br />
>   </ul>
>    </xsl:template>
>   </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```

I am trying for out put as below:

On load of Html only Fname will be displayed like

> ```
>   John
>   Tim
> ```
>
> Both are having link to open child
>   onclick on John, only Admin is showing as below
>
> ```
>  John
>      Admin: 01/01/2015
> ```

Report: ABC is not showing.

Expected

> ```
>   John
>        Admin:01/01/2015
>        Report:ABC
> ```

If i remove the event and display:none it is showing both Admin and Report.

What i am doing wrong here.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns to be  more of a javascript problem than XSL. You simply need to 'toggle display' all relevant `<ul>` elements instead of only the first one -the one at index 0- :

```
<a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">
    <xsl:value-of select="report/Fname"/>
</a>
```

And accommodate toggling multiple elements in the JS function definition. This is the only bit of XML/XSL in this answer, you can wrap JS codes within `CDATA` element just for convenient (to avoid necessity to escape XML special characters like `<`, `>`, etc. especially when the function getting more and more complex) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[
    function toggleDisplay(element) 
    { 
        element.style.display = element.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; 
    };
    function toggleDisplayAll(elements) 
    { 
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            toggleDisplay(elements[i]);
        }
    }   
  ]]>
</script>
```